# Глобальные переменные js ошибка

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Есть код, в котором я создаю переменную price, но не могу ее использовать ниже, так как получаю ошибку  Cannot access 'price' before initialization, что сделано не так?

```js
async function getCart() {
    var price = 0;
    fetch(base_api_path + '/cart/getAllOrders', {
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            res.forEach(income => {
                price += income.price;
                ....
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1407586/191482

Comment: price у тебя где-то ещё похоже и именно там ты пытаешься к нему обратиться..

Comment: скорее всего внутри `getCart` есть объявление `let price` либо `const price`. Вероятнее всего где-то тут: `....`